# Function parameter with a dot gives SyntaxError

Tags: python, parameters, syntax-error

I am trying to run a Python script from a command line and this is my script:

```
import sys

def printsomething(sys.argv):
    text = str(sys.argv[1])
    print(text)

    return "done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    printsomething()
```

I am getting `syntax error` for this line:
`def printsomething(sys.argv)`

What is the problem?

My command line command is this:

```
python myscript.py trololo
```

Comment: consider working with [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). It is a convenient interface for working with command-line arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys.argv` is python reserved word and not recommended to use as method arguments and also period is not allowed in python identifiers.

[Identifiers and keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

> Within the ASCII range (U+0001..U+007F), the valid characters for identifiers are the same as in Python 2.x: the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, except for the first character, the digits 0 through 9.

Just use valid identifier for method argument and call `printsomething` by passing `sys.argv`

```
import sys

def printsomething(v):
   text = str(v[1])
   print(text)

   return "done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  printsomething(sys.argv)
```

**Note** `sys.argv` is a list and throws `IndexError` if index is out of range

Answer (score 1):

The expressions you should put inside the brackets are the function argument names.
Function argument names can't include dot inside them. If you want to use sys inside your function simply use it, its a global import.

```
import sys

def printsomething():
    text = str(sys.argv[1])
    print(text)

    return "done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    printsomething()
```